# rtabmap_ros in simulation

Tags: slam, navigation, rtabmap-ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to launch the database file and publish it to ROS when running in simulation, i.e. when the sensors are not connected? I would just use it for visualization and for generating the collision scene, not for localization. By simulation, I don't mean in a physics engine like Gazebo.

I just want the cloud_map topic to exist including the service to visualize the map in RViz. I don't want any data from the time of creating the map to be replayed, especially the tf frames. Ideally, `rtabmap_ros rtabmap.launch` is not launched.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/316492/rtabmap_ros-in-simulation/) by [achille](https://answers.ros.org/users/30659/achille/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2019-02-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Note sure I understand well the question, but there is what you can do with a database:

1. Play database like a rosbag (though it is recommended to use directly a rosbag if it is what you want to do):

`$ rosrun rtabmap_ros data_player _database:=~/my_map.db --clock`

2. Start rtabmap with the database as input, then subscribe to `/rtabmap/cloud_map` and call service `/rtabmap/publish_map` to get the map:

   $ roslaunch rtabmap_ros rtabmap.launch database_path:=~/my_map.db
   $ rostopic echo /rtabmap/cloud_map
   $ rosservice call /rtabmap/publish_map 1 1 0

**EDIT**

3. Without rtabmap.launch:

   $ roscore
   $ export ROS_NAMESPACE=rtabmap && rosrun rtabmap_ros rtabmap _database_path:=~/my_map.db
   $ rostopic echo /rtabmap/cloud_map
   $ rosservice call /rtabmap/publish_map 1 1 0
4. For RVIZ with [rtabmap_ros/MapCloud](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros#Map_Cloud_Display) display, launch rtabmap node in rtabmap namespace, then in RVIZ's MapCloud plugin should be able to click on Download Map:

   $ roscore
   $ export ROS_NAMESPACE=rtabmap && rosrun rtabmap_ros rtabmap _database_path:=~/my_map.db
   $ rviz
5. For rtabmapviz, we can do something similar:

   $ roscore
   $ export ROS_NAMESPACE=rtabmap && rosrun rtabmap_ros rtabmap _database_path:=~/my_map.db
   $ export ROS_NAMESPACE=rtabmap && rosrun rtabmap_ros rtabmapviz

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2019-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [achille](https://answers.ros.org/users/30659/achille/) on 2019-02-28**:
This works but given more thought it's not what I'm looking for. I updated my question with more details

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2019-03-03**:
updated the answer with more examples

**Comment by [achille](https://answers.ros.org/users/30659/achille/) on 2019-03-12**:
The edited answer works for me with Rviz when the namespace is set to `export ROS_NAMESPACE=rtabmap/rtabmap` instead of just `rtabmap`. However I get the `Did not receive data since 5 seconds!` on the rtabmap node. Can mapping not just be disabled? I do have the ability to suppress warnings but I'm hoping there's an actual fix.

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2019-03-15**:
you can set `_publish_tf:=false` to disable map->odom to be published.

**Comment by [achille](https://answers.ros.org/users/30659/achille/) on 2019-03-19**:
That doesn't get rid of the warnings. The rtabmap localization node is still running and looking for messages on the camera topics.

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2019-03-22**:
If there are warnings telling that camera topics are not received since 5 seconds, and you don't plan to feed topics to the node, you can ignore the warnings (rtabmap is waiting for topics and do nothing actually).

**Comment by [achille](https://answers.ros.org/users/30659/achille/) on 2019-03-25**:
Solved the warnings by setting the `output` argument to 'log' when running in simulation. Thanks!